# HTML\PHP - How to elicit user (visitor)'s info

Tags: javascript, html, tcp, information-retrieval

How to elicit user's information when he/she is visiting your website?

- IP Address
- Mac Address
- User Profile Name
- OS Name
- OS version
- OS Registered to (Name/Company)
- Computer Name
- Browser Name
- Browser Version
- ISP Name/Internet Connection Provider Name
- Connection Type
- Location - City/Country (based on IP)

Comment: example for some of it... http://whatismyipaddress.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to most of what you're asking is either 'impossible', 'impossible with javascript, use ajax to get it from the server-side', or 'parse the user string' (which can always be spoofed).

- IP Address: You have to use a serverside language. If you need it dynamically, you can get it from an AJAX call. In PHP, it's `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`
- Mac Address: Not available, [except very very rarely](http://neilkilbride.blogspot.com/2008/02/finding-user-mac-address-javascript.html) if the user is using IE and has poor security settings.
- OS, OS Version: You can get it by parsing the User Agent String. A script like this can do it pretty robustly: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html
- OS registered to: Impossible.
- Computer Name: Impossible.
- Browser Name, Browser Version: You can get it by parsing the User Agent String. A script like this can do it pretty robustly: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html
- ISP: You'll need to use some kind of 3rd party database for querying who owns an IP. Or, you can call a command line 'whois'. In PHP, that would look like `shell_exec("whois $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']")`; that would return the whois record for that IP address, which you can parse to get an ISP.
- Location: You'll need to use some kind of 3rd party tool to associate an IP address with a general region. (something like this: http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php)